# Not able to send data to BLE Peripheral (ZL-RC04A) device

Tags: android, ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to write data using code snippet.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral1 didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Again, we loop through the array, just in case.
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        // And check if it's the right one
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
            NSString *payloadMessage = @"3N";
            NSData *payload = [payloadMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [_discoveredPeripheral discoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:characteristic];
            [_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:payload forCharacteristic:characteristic
                              type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
            [_discoveredPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];

        }
    }

}
```

**But getting error in**

```
 - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(nullable NSError *)error
{

}
```

**As:**
**`Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}`**

Although same is working android.

Comment: What are the `properties` of that `characteristic`?

Comment: <CBCharacteristic: 0x1700b8420, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = (null), notifying = YES>

Comment: 0x16, that's 0x10+0x2+0x04, no? Then it's `CBCharacteristicPropertyRead = 0x02, CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse = 0x04, CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify = 0x10,` So you can't do `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` (doesn't include `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite = 0x08,`), you need to do it with `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error if you use the wrong write type for the characteristic (given the characteristic is writable after all). There are two types of writing data to a characteristic:

1. `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`: In this case you will get an acknowledge packet by the peripheral. You can think of this as a TCP packet.
2. `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`: This is a "fire and forget" kind of write. You can think of this as a UDP packet.

Therefore, try to use `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` instead of `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`. If that does not work as well you might have to check if your characteristic is writable after all.

Comment: i tried CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse too , but its too not working . 

How to know if CBCharacteristic is writable ?

But its working in android, that means it must be writable i guess.

Comment: Seems to be exactly the case of a WithResponse when WithResponse it not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592772/not-able-to-send-data-to-ble-peripheral-zl-rc04a-device?noredirect=1#comment78145166_45592772

Comment: Which error do you get when using `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`?

Comment: Could you do `if (characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse) {NSLog(@"Able to write without response");} if (characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithResponse) {NSLog(@"Able to write with response");}` and show us what you get? Also as @Jens Meder suggest, is the error the same without response? Or is is a bad format of the data sent?

Comment: @JensMeder not getting any Error as there is no callback. Actually i have relay having LED , which will enlighten when given input as "3N".

Comment: @Larme i am not sure for format , if you can suggest me for format .Actually  i need to send inputs to light-ON 3N and to make off 3F. When same doing in android.

Comment: When same doing in android its working.  Here is android code snippet   
 commands[0]=numPort+"N";
 commands[1]=numPort+"F";
 connectAndControl.openGate(bluetoothMAC,commands[0]);//On   
 connectAndControl.openGate(bluetoothMAC,commands[1]);//Off

    public void openGate(String bluetoothMAC, String command)
    {
        mConnectedThread.write(command);
//        mConnectedThread.write("1N");
    }

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java and less with Bluetooth in Java, but I'm wondering what does really send `connectAndControl.openGate(bluetoothMAC,commands[1])` to the device. In other is `dataUsingEncoding:` (the way you use to transform your `NSString` to `NSData`) really the way to do.

Comment: I debugged in android 

     byte[] value = {-59, 49, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56,-86};
     mBluetoothLeService.WriteBytes(value); //ON                                             
     byte[] value = {-59, 50, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56,-86};
    mBluetoothLeService.WriteBytes(value); //OFF

Comment: Your payload is `334e` for `3N`. That clearly doesn't match the data send with Android. It seems to be missing some part of the data.